# How to show popup in php instead of new page

Tags: php, popup, alert

I am new to php. I just want to ask how to show login failure message as a POPUP and not on a new page. What should I replace on the command "`print`"?

```
if($login_check > 0){ 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    // Get member ID into a session variable
    $id = $row["id"];   
    session_register('id'); 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    // Get member username into a session variable
    $username = $row["username"];   
    session_register('username'); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    // Update last_log_date field for this member now
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$id'"); 
    // Print success message here if all went well then exit the script
    header("location: member_profile.php?id=$id"); 
    exit();
  } // close while
} else {
   // Print LOGIN FAILURE MESSAGE to the user and link them back to your login page
     print '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">No match in our records, try again </font>       <br />
   <br /><a href="login.php">Click here</a> to go back to the login page.';
     exit();
}
```

Comment: You can't do that easy. You'll have to use JavaScript and AJAX to get this working reliably.

Comment: `window.open` in javascript

Comment: *sidenote:* font tag is deprecated. use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go for javascript alerts or some jquery custom popups.

There is one jquery plugin Impromptu, in which you can show customized popups. It also has other features.

You can display Login failure message as show below along with the callback to go back to previous page :

```
$.prompt('Login Failed',{
  close: function(){               
   window.location.href = "page_url";
  }
});
```

for more details, refer to [this link](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/)

Comment: Ayu, you may try to implement it. :)

Comment: You need to put above code in else part as : else {
    print '$.prompt("Login Failed",{
  close: function(){               
   window.location.href = "page_url";
  }
});';
     exit();
}